# how float 0.5 and double 0.5 are equal

Tags: c

```
float   num = 0.5;
double num2 = 0.5;
if( num == num2)
   printf("Equal");
else
   printf("Not Equal");
```

How is it possible?

1. The binary value of float 0.5 is `00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000`
2. The binary value of double 0.5 is `00111111 11100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`

Please explain step by step because I'm new to programming

Comment: Java, C, or C++ ?

Comment: Your code is not getting compiled only, if in Java.

Comment: Because the compiler (or runtime interpreter) doesn't compare bit-patterns?

Comment: This is about `structured programming`. So I guess dont spam keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the comparison, the `float` value is implicitly converted to type `double`.

Then the two values **of the same type** are compared.

Comment: according to your perspective float 0.1 implicitly converted to double and result will be equal(true) ...But actual result is Not Equal(false)..

Comment: @munyasamyv: In the statement `float x = 0.1;`, the `double` value of `0.1` is converted to `float` type losing precision. Later, when comparing the value with loss of precision (after conversion to `double`) with another (`double`) `0.1` they are different. In other words `(double)(float)0.1 != 0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You should look up IEEE764 float and double definitions to see how real numbers are really stored, and what the binary-point offsets are for floats and doubles. The endian-ness of the machine will also affect things.